# Multiple Response AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there a way to have one AJAX request with multiple responses?

For example, if make a GET request to the server which will take a long time to calculate, how could I have the server occasionally send back responses which give me some data about the progress?

If so, could somebody post an example, preferably with Jquery and an explanation of the mechanism through which the server can does it?

Comment: What serverside language/framework are you using?

Comment: It doesn't matter, because it's impossible

Comment: @The Scrum Meister C#/ASP.NET

Comment: How long could be the wait, for example?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can implement this using 2 ajax calls, one to run the process and a second call to periodically poll the progress:

On the server side:

```
public class ProgressInfo
{
    public int Percent {get;set;}
    public bool Done {get;set;}
}

public JsonResult DoCalculation(string id)
{
    ProgressInfo progress = new ProgressInfo();
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
    {
        Session[id] = progress;
    }

    //periodicly update progress
    progress.Percent++;
}

public JsonResult GetProgress(string id)
{
    ProgressInfo progress;
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)
        || (progress = Session[id] as ProgressInfo) == null)
    {
        return Json(new {
            success = false
        });
    }
    if(progress.done)
    {
        Session.Remove(id);
    }
    return Json(new {
        success = true,
        done = progress.done,
        percent = progress.Percent
    });
}
```

On the client side:

```
var progressID = Math.random();

function doCalculation() {
    $.post('<%=Url.Action("DoCalcluation")%>/' + progressID);
    setTimeout(pollProgress, 1000);
}

function pollProgress() {
    $.post('<%=Url.Action("GetProgress")%>/' + progressID, function(response){
        if(!response.success) {
            alert('Cannot find progress');
            return;
        }
            if(response.done) {
                alert('Done!');
            } else {
            alert('Progress at ' + response.precent + '%');
            setTimeout(pollProgress, 1000 /*1 second*/);
            }
    }, 'json');
}
```

Comment: Clever, I like it! I hadn't though about using the session to store the progress data.

Comment: @peter-of-the-corn There are other ways to do it. Look into [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)). If you do use this solution, make sure to validate the `id` parameter so a malicious user will not be able to overwrite the entire session.

Answer (score 6):

Fast answer: No, it isn't possible.

You should send more requests to get more responses

Comment: But the code would have to restart at the beginning if I sent another request. :(

Comment: Restart means to start over or do again.

Comment: @genesis With what I am doing, it's not possible.

Comment: why? Why it isn't possible? Explain it little bit more

Comment: The code is in a loop and the steps it will take are not predictable prior to runtime. Thus, the code cannot be divided into separate steps

Answer (score 1):

You most likely need help from the server side coding because looks like you need reverse ajax or what is also called comet push. I do not know which language you use on server side but the basic idea is to delay http response for as long as browser will allow using endless loop (on server side) and push data while connection is alive

You may want to check this out:
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/ServerPushFAQ

Comment: DO you mean to output buffer data before script ends? Nice idea but very complicated and required fine apache/php configuration

Comment: yes it can get complicated if you code your own handlers for this but for a large scale there are products like WebSync to handle server push.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at xajax it can send multiple responses back, and one can ever redirect them to certain areas. In this regard xajax is much better than jQuery. I can make one request and the server can compose a response which contains multiple responses either HTML, JavaScript, calls, etc. You can even say put this there and that there with options like append, replace etc. very cool. jQuery should do this then I can switch once and for all to jQuery... This is the only thing that is keeping me from switching over.

Comment: XAJAX is only for PHP, and it only transfers data with XML.

Answer (score 0):

One Ajax request ----------->You get One response.

What you can actually do is.

check the response data 
and 
do DIFFERENT action as per the data fetched.